# Java CS6 How to convert ai to fla + html + swf using a script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I would like some assistance with batch image processing - I need to save an vector ai image to fla+html+swf file formats using a script - What I have done is to open the software and open a folder with these image's in. Please advise how i can write a script to assist with this process as I have alot of images I have to save.

I need to save it in actionscript 3 and actionscript 2, so if there is a script that convert it from actionscript 3 to actionscipt 2 that can be usefull aswell.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to put an image found inside an .AI-file (Adobe Illustrator) and automatically place that image into two newly created .FLA-files (one with AS3 set as default programming language and one set with AS2 as the default programming language)?

There is no quick and easy solution for this, it would require a combination of a "main app (python, c#, java or similar)" combined with "JSFL" to do what you want. And in the end that app would probably become very complex.

If you can skip the requirement of each ai-file becoming a unique fla-file you can just import all the images into a newly created FLA-file. But if that's not an option, then you're most definitely out of luck :\